# show a tooltip on a disabled image link (JSP)

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have a popup menu that shows a series of images and each of them contains a different link.

a single element of a menu looks like this:

```
<li class="button-link" data-idp="idfirst">
<s:a href='%{linkMethod("linked")}' class="original-styling blocked"><span class="sr-only">Linked ID</span><img src="LinkedImage" onerror="this.src='ErrorImg'; this.onerror=null;" alt="linked ID" /></s:a>
```

Css styles are just for styling except the blocked one, which looks like this:

```
.original-styling.blocked {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

In the case of a block, I would also like to add something that looks and behaves like this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

but I can't make it work, I even tried the title attribute but when .blocked is active, it won't show up, I would even be happy with just the working title.

My main limitation is that I can't use jquery, javascript and other "modern" stuff, just JSP struts and java of course.

Any clues? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `pointer-events: none;` attribute then it is not possible for the tooltip popup to show when the mouse hovers over it.

However, if you added a `disabled` tag to your html element then you could get the functionality of a blocked link and still be able to have the tooltip work.

Here is a working example, hope it works for you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

.originalStyling.blocked {
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.originalStyling .originalStylingtext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.originalStyling:hover .originalStylingtext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body>

<s:a href="%{linkMethod("linked")}" class="originalStyling blocked" disabled>Linked ID
  <span class="originalStylingtext">
    <img src="https://techcabal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/css3.jpg" onerror="this.src='ErrorImg'; this.onerror=null;" alt="linked ID" style="width:90%" />
  </span>
</s:a>


</body>
</html>
```